# In Matlab: how do I quickly create smoothing matrices?

Tags: matlab

Say I have 5 measurements of a signal as a column vector: x. 
I can smooth the signal by multiplying it with a smoothing matrix:

$\ \mathbf{xs=S*x} $

For instance I might use [1 2 1] as a smoothing kernel in which case I get:

```
S =
     2     1     0     0     0
     1     2     1     0     0
     0     1     2     1     0
     0     0     1     2     1
     0     0     0     1     2
```

So far I have been using the function sparse() to build the matrix diagonal by diagonal,
but this quickly becomes tedious.

**How can I quickly create a mxm smoothing matrix from a 1xn convolution kernel in Matlab?**

Comment: Why don't you use `filter` instead? Something like `filter([1 2 1],1,x)`

Comment: Convolve seems a good candidate, too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following-

```
kernel = [1 2 1];
s = conv2(eye(numMeasurements), kernel, 'same')
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. That works fine, but is there not some matrix operation: S=operation(eye(n,n),kernel) ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Andy Changed the solution to make it much more compact and more like you want, I think.

Comment: Thanks Jim! Something like that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry I can't comment yet, but just in case you didn't know, you could define a function in another .m file and use it like your suggested "S=operation(eye(n,n),kernel)" if that's what you really want.

Comment: @wrapperapps Comment converted :)